# Access native mongoDB collection in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am using this [ShareJS package](https://atmospherejs.com/mizzao/sharejs) in my Meteor application. ShareJS uses the collections `docs` and `ops`. How can I access these collections from the server?
Do I have to define them as collections as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `MongoInternals`. But make sure to wrap it in a `Future` for it to behave correctly. I like the following `IIFE` pattern the most:

```
var connection = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo;

var searchResults = (function(collectionName, query) {

    var future = new Future(); 

    connection._getCollection(collectionName)
      .find(query)
      .toArray(function(error, results) {
        if(error) future.throw(error);
        else future.return(results || []);
      });      

    return future.wait();

})(options);
```